# How can work on a field which is added in $project stage

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have this data in my database(only relative parts are provided here)    :

```
[
  {
    "geojson": 5,
    "entity_status_update": "2021-12-28T10:16:58.000+00:00"
  },
  {
    "geojson": 7,
    "entity_status_update": "2021-12-03T10:16:58.000+00:00"
  },
  {
    "geojson": 2,
    "entity_status_update": "2021-11-08T10:16:58.000+00:00"
  }
]
```

I am trying to add a new field called `deadline` which should be equal to `entity_status_update`+`geojson` days. I am using `$dateAdd` method of mongodb for the addition. My problem is I can't find a way to use `days_to_add` in my query. I think the reason is, it is in the `$project` stage yet.

```
[ 
  { 
    "$project": {
      "days_to_add": "$geo_json",                   // use this
      "deadline": {
        "$dateAdd": {
          "startDate": "$entity_status_update",
            "unit": "day",
            "amount": "$days_to_add"                // in here
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I must not directly use `geojson` in the calculation.

Comment: in your sample data it's `geojson` and you're passing `geo_json` in `$project` and can you tell why you must not use `geojson` directly in the calculation? btw why don't you add `days_to_add` fild using `$addFields` and use it in your `$project` stage? [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aryV6HkWgXi)

Comment: I added `geojson` field just to explain my situation. Actually  I get the `days_to_add` with a $switch case in the same $project stage

Comment: @1sina1  Thanks. You saved my day. Can you post your comment as an answer so that it could be helpful for others later on?

Comment: yw, ansnwer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `days_to_add` using `$addFields` and then use it in your `$project` stage

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aryV6HkWgXi)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "days_to_add": "$geojson"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "days_to_add": 1,
      "deadline": {
        "$dateAdd": {
          "startDate": "$entity_status_update",
          "unit": "day",
          "amount": "$days_to_add"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```